# What's the sytax for importing all Math functions in ECMA 6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have something like this:

```
import * as math from "lib/math";
alert("2π = " + math.sum(math.pi, math.pi));
```

And I know this is possible:

```
import {sum, pi} from "lib/math";
alert("2π = " + sum(pi, pi));
```

But is there a way to import all Math functions in my namespace at once? Something like this?

```
import {*} from "lib/math";
alert("2π = " + sum(pi, pi));
```

or even this?

```
import from "lib/math"; //compiles fine in Babel but isn't in spec
alert("2π = " + sum(pi, pi));
```

Comment: `import from "lib/math";` doesn't compile in Babel, FYI, or do you mean `import "lib/math";`? Felix is correct though. Providing a name is necessary so you can know whether a variable is referencing a module import, or a global variable, at parse time. This is the same reason `with(){}` statements aren't allowed in strict-mode code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not. Not sure what else to say about it other than referring you to the [spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-source-text-module-records).